# In references the Update User Import is greyed out

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, namespaces

I am receiving errors with my Imports statement in my project. It does not recognize the namespace. In my References tab in Properties for my project the reference is there however in the Imported namespaces section I can check or uncheck a namespace but the Update User Import button is greyed out. Additionally, in my code I cannot directly reference the namespace either. I am working with CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine reference.

Comment: Your post is unclear. Adding images to your post may be helpful. Are you using _.NET Framework_ or _.NET_? What version?